# Could not initialize class javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayer

Tags: java, audio, mp3, javasound

I am making a game where the player can download the sound from the newground, this sound is downloaded in mp3 format. I added the Javazoom library to play this sound, but the code throws an error: "Could not initialize class javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayer".

```
import javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayer;

@Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        BasicPlayer player = new BasicPlayer();
        try {
            player.open(new File(soundId+".mp3"));//soundId - id of the sound on newgrounds
            player.play();
        } catch (BasicPlayerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might want to post the full stack trace, if you're still interested in a solution.